# Dynamic select sentence with LINQ - Join 2 DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a question related with a issue that give the Visual Studio when I try to generate a generic select sentence in LINQ

Main code:

```
private void DynamicLinq()
{
    DataTable Table1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable Table2 = new DataTable();

    // CREATE COLUMNS AND FILL THE DATATABLES

    string SelectString = "a.Amount, b.User"; // Generic selection of fields

    var vLINQ = (from a in Table1.AsEnumerable()
                 join b in Table2.AsEnumerable()
                 on a.Field<Object>("ID") equals b.Field<Object>("ID")
                 into Group
                 from q in Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select q).Select(SelectString);
}
```

This is the additional class that have the project:

```
public class SelectBuilder<T, T>
{
    Func<T, T> CreateNewStatement(string fields)
    {
        // input parameter "o"
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

        // new statement "new Data()"
        var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(T));

        // create initializers
        var bindings = fields.Split(',').Select(o => o.Trim())
            .Select(o =>
            {

                // property "Field1"
                var mi = typeof(T).GetProperty(o);

                // original value "o.Field1"
                var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, mi);

                // set value "Field1 = o.Field1"
                return (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
            }
        );

        // initialization "new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var xInit = Expression.MemberInit(xNew, bindings);

        // expression "o => new Data { Field1 = o.Field1, Field2 = o.Field2 }"
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(xInit, xParameter);

        // compile to Func<Data, Data>
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

And this is the error that shows me the VisualStudio:

> (local variable) string SelectString
>   Error:
>
> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   type arguments explicitly.

Seems that the problem is directly with the additional class.

Comment: Avoid asking questions like "has anyone faced this problem before?" It's not relevant.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but linq's select doesnt have a string overload.  It cant determine what type its supposed to return, hence the error.

Comment: @paqogomez you can see the full size of the screenshot open it in a new tab. Seems that the problem is where the LINQ does recognize the result as DataRows.

Comment: Just FYI, if you're trying to get Dynamic LINQ, Microsoft already created the library for you: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: @entropic I currently use this solution in VB.NET to create the Joins, but in C# doesn't work as expected... then, I try another solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround with the [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) implementation:

```
IQueryable linqData = (from row1 in dtMain.AsEnumerable()
                       join row2 in dtSec.AsEnumerable()
                       on row1.Field<Object>("frameworkIdTemporal1") equals row2.Field<Object>("frameworkIdTemporalSec1")
                       into result
                       from subRight in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select
                       new { row1, row3 = (subRight == null) ? (dtSec.NewRow()) : subRight })
                       .AsQueryable().Select(strSelect);
```

I share the piece of the code with the LINQ